# Typedef redefinition with different types ('uint_least16_t' (aka 'unsigned short') vs 'char16_t')

Tags: c++, objective-c, swift, xcode7, swift2

My project contains Swift 2.2, Objective C and C++ with Xcode 7.3

I am getting the following errors in the generated ProducModuleName-Swift.h file

```
Typedef redefinition with different types ('uint_least16_t' (aka 'unsigned short') vs 'char16_t')
Typedef redefinition with different types ('uint_least32_t' (aka 'unsigned int') vs 'char32_t')
```

at the following section

```
if !defined(SWIFT_TYPEDEFS)
# define SWIFT_TYPEDEFS 1
# if defined(__has_include) && __has_include(<uchar.h>)
#  include <uchar.h>
# elif !defined(__cplusplus) || __cplusplus < 201103L
typedef uint_least16_t char16_t;
typedef uint_least32_t char32_t;
# endif
```

I can by bypass the error by changing my C++ parms to C++ 11 which will skip this troublesome code.

However I would like to know if there is a cleaner solution to this.

[image: **enter image description here**]

To clarify the code above is the code which XCode generates when compiling. I have no control over this code

Comment: `uint_least16_t` and `uint_least32_t` are [C++11 types](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer).

Comment: `char16_t` is a keyword in C++ starting with C++11. You cannot use it as a typedef name.

Comment: Looks like you also need to `#include <stdint.h>` in that second conditional block.

Comment: The code is not my code this is the code which is generated by XCode

Comment: The error occurs when you include "ProducModuleName-Swift.h" from a C++ file? What would a minimal C++ file exhibiting the problem be?

Comment: @MartinR That seems to be the problem, what I was trying to do was to cast my enums from C++ enums to Swift enums. I will find another solution. I had included #import "Fathomit-Swift.h" in my .mm file. If you put your suggestion as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: What suggestion? I just asked for clarification because I could not reproduce the issue! I am happy to write an answer if I have understood the real problem, which is not yet the case.

Comment: My problem was that I included #import "Fathomit-Swift.h" in my .mm file.  I am not sure if this is forbidden or if it is forbidden for c++ < 11. Removing it fixes my issue or I can just specify the c++ version. I understand a little more than before